# Why all cookies changes when another user logs in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

i have a web page in hosting server, but my problem is this, i'm storing current user id inside a cookie when the user get sign in, but when another user login from the another computer or the another browser, all cookies changes for all users

this is my code when the user login

```
HttpCookie mcookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfoOne");
mcookie["id_usu"] = dt.Rows[0]["id_usu"].ToString();
mcookie["tipo_usu"] = dt.Rows[0]["tipo"].ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(mcookie);
```

Comment: How did you reproduce this issue? What is `dt.Rows[0]["id_usu"]` and how is it obtained? You need to give us something to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing id_usu and tipo are columns from a database. Are these value unique per user, or are you reading the same value for every user? Or is dt a static variable, meaning it's shared between all users?

Comment: dt is a datatable, dt firing from the database with the user login info, id_usu and tipo in this case